# Hat over rep when picture is missing

Tags: bug, profile-picture, winter-bash

My Facebook picture got de-synchronized after I activated e-mail login and I have never updated it (and I don't have a profile picture). With the new winter bash hat-over-picture feature I'm experiencing this bug (please ignore the dark theme):

[image: bug-picture]

As you see, the hat stacks over the rep area! (Firefox 60.4.0esr (32-bit))

Comment: Looks fine on Firefox 64.0 (64bit). **However**, the hat is actually out of the profile picture window on **your profile page** and overlaying your profile description.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+F5?

Comment: Have you tried spacer.gif?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Hat? Just kidding...:-)

Comment: Hats are important. They overrule everything!

Comment: @CinCout As the OP mentions in the title: `hats OVER rep` ;)

Comment: Have you considered updating the profile picture?

Comment: @CinCout I don't really mind the _"problem"_ the bug causes, just reporting it for the bug's sake

Comment: I am just giving possible alternatives because hats matter :D